# JavaFX module javafx.graphics

Tags: javafx, java-11

Upon fixing a requires issue with robot.awt I've now encountered another problem upon running my application. Application builds with no issues. Stack trace :

```
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class reports.Main
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:890)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl (in module javafx.graphics) cannot access class reports.Main (in module Reports) because module Reports does not export reports to module javafx.graphics
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:802)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The root cause for the issue is contained in this line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl (in module javafx.graphics) cannot access class reports.Main (in module Reports) because module Reports does not export reports to module javafx.graphics
```

`Application.launch` uses reflection to create a instance of the application class using reflection. External classes like `Application` are only allowed to access your classes via reflections if the class recides in a package that is opened or exported to `Application`'s module (`javafx.graphics`).

You need to add one of the following lines your `Reports` module declaration:

```
exports reports;
opens reports to javafx.graphics;
```

The last line should be preferred since it's the more restrictive one. If the unless the `reports` package also contains e.g. a `main` class/method, you should use the first line.

Comment: Just to note, since JavaFX requires both the `Application` subclass and its no-arg constructor be public, using a qualified exports directive would work as well (i.e. `exports reports to javafx.graphics`).

Comment: `module-info.java`

Answer (score 0):

- As mentioned in above answer Application.launch uses reflection to
  create an instance of the Application class with the help of java
  reflection
- **But because of modules, reflection is inaccessible by default.**
- There are some cases where you have to enable reflection for your
  classes, In your case you will have to enable the reflection of your
  package named reports to the module javafx.graphics to let JavaFX
  work.
- So, you need to modularize your application coz, JDK, JRE and JavaFX
  are modularized hence; create a new file **module-info.java** inside
  package **src/main/java** with below statements inside reports module block.

> `module reports {`
>
> `requires javafx.controls;`
>
> `requires javafx.media;`
>
> `opens reports to javafx.graphics;`
>
> `}`

- File **module-info.java** will define your application as a module named
  *reports* and your module requires some modules like (*javafx.controls*
  and *javafx.media*) in order to work.

> Note: Module name *reports* is taken from your package name of **Main**
> class.
>
> **Why module?**
> Modules are a new way to organize your applications and
> libraries, it also enable strong encapsulation and
> implementation/reflection hiding.